# How to use var element with value-less attribute in ReactJS JSX?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to wrap a simple var element around a number such that the DOM would look something like this:

```
<span><var number>30</var> minutes</span>
```

The JSX that I thought would accomplish this looks like this:

```
<span><var number>{mins}</var> minutes</span>
```

But this results in the error:

> Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `number`.

And the attribute get stripped out so my DOM ends up looking like this:

```
<span><var>30</var> minutes</span>
```

I have also tried "data-number" instead of "number" and this is possibly closer but still not what I want. It results in the DOM looking like this:

```
<span><var data-number="true">30</var> minutes</span>
```

which is not acceptable for my use case. Does anyone know how to get React to leave my value-less attributes alone?

Comment: There is no such attribute `number` in `<var>` element, what do you expect to happen? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/var#:~:text=The%20HTML%20Variable%20element%20(%20%3Cvar,that%20behavior%20is%20browser%2Ddependent.

Comment: @DennisVash it's my understanding you can include global attributes which would include "data-number" as a valid attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<span><var number>${mins}</var> minutes</span>` }} />
```

Comment: How will it render a HTML element?

Comment: Oops, I misread. I through he was trying to display text